# Using underscore to find matching property in a array with objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this:

```
var members: [
{
   id:1,
   user:{
     name: 'John Smith',
     email:'john@gmail.com'
   }
},
{
   id:2,
   user:{
     name: 'Jane Smith',
     email:'jane@gmail.com'
   }
}]
```

I need the member object with email as the criteria.

I tried:

```
_.findWhere(members, {user.email: 'john@gmail.com'})
```

No luck.

Comment: `{user.email …` is a syntax error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not looking for a simple attribute AFAIK you can't use findWhere. Instead you can either use indexBy to get a rearranged collection (good for many similar lookups) or find with a test function (good for occasional lookups):

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/tshpfz0x/3/
var members = [{
   id: 1,
   user: {
       name: 'John Smith',
       email: 'john@gmail.com'
   }
}, {
   id: 2,
   user: {
       name: 'Jane Smith',
       email: 'jane@gmail.com'
   }
}];

console.info(_.findWhere(members, {
    user: {
        email: 'john@gmail.com'
    }
})); // undefined

function byEmail(member) {return member.user.email;}

console.info(
   _.indexBy(members, byEmail)["john@gmail.com"]
); // Object

console.info(
   _.find(members, function (member) {
       return (byEmail(member) === "john@gmail.com");})
); // Object
```